# How to install rpm file on a remote machine?

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, remote-access, rpm, remote-server

I have a rpm file in s3 bucket(the link is open to public).
This rpm file I need to install on a remote machine as part of pipeline.

The gitlab pipeline will be using a runner(machineA) (alpine linux container).
This machineA will be passed with parameters ADMIN_SERVER_IP ,ADMIN_SERVER_USER and ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY(raw text of ssh pem file).
With these parameters, from machineA, I need to install the rpm file on machineB(ADMIN_SERVER_IP).

I tried as

```
echo $ADMIN_SERVER_SSH_KEY > sshkey.pem
echo "yum install -y rpmfilelink" | ssh -tt -i sshkey.pem $ADMIN_SERVER_USER@$ADMIN_SERVER_IP
```

but it just stuck there, so added exit 0 at the end.
And it simply returning success even for error.

Please suggest good command to remote install a rpm file on a remote machine

Comment: rpmfilelink is not variable, just a dummy text so viewers can undestand there wil be a http file link to an rpm file, can you share the full command?

Comment: the command I shared takes the same effect. But I tried again as you provided, same result. Showing result as success whether failure/success